# sample distribution of frequency

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, sampling

Suppose that a proportion $p$ of a given population verifies a given characteristic.

Let $X$ denote the random variable that equals the number of times this characteristic is observed in a sample of size $n$ (so $X$ follows a binomial distribution of parameters $(n,p)$), and let $F=\frac{X}{n}$ denote the corresponding frequency.

Sampling theory tells us that under some conditions, $F$ approximately follows a normal distribution with parameters $(p,\sqrt{p(1-p)/n})$, and this can be used to compute the probability $P(F \le f)$.

My question is, instead of using this approximation, why can't we use the fact that the distribution of $X$ is known, and that
$
P(F \le f) = P(\frac{X}{n} \le f) = P(X \le f \cdot n)
$
?
Wouldn't this give the exact probability ? Is there a reason why the normal distribution is preferred ?

Comment: Is your question the same as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247904/why-use-the-normal-approximation-to-the-binomial)?

Comment: Perhaps. But I am also wondering if it is not simply incorrect from a theoretical point of view to use the binomial.